# Использование Stream для изменения списка строк

Tags: java, java-stream

Подскажите, имеется список в котором содержатся названия всех файлов из определенного каталога

```
List<String> files = Arrays.stream(directory.list()).filter(f -> f.endsWith(".man")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Каким образом можно составить аналогичный список в котором содержатся названия файлов без расширения? (т.е. результат список файлов с расширением ".man", но в списке без него). Спасибо

Comment: Вообще без любого расширения или конкретно без man?

Comment: Нужно убрать расширение или отобрать те которые уже без расширения?

Comment: Добавлю вопрос. Список должен быть такой, но в нем содержатся только названия файлов, например файлы "1.man", "2.man", "ее.man" -> Список "1","2","ее"

Comment: Именно без ".man"

Comment: Написал ответ, проверяйте, ставьте мне галочку правильного ответа если решение верное))

Comment: Элементарная ошибка, которая решается добавлением одного восклицательного знака. Мне кажется, этот вопрос не несёт пользы обществу. Лично я бы его на вашем месте удалил.

Comment: У меня решение в две строки, но хочу найти в одну List<String> files = Arrays.stream(directory.list()).filter(f -> f.endsWith(".man")).collect(Collectors.toList());
            List<String> namesfiles = files.stream().map(f -> f.replaceAll(".man","")).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: Исправил решение, проверяйте, подходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<String> files = Arrays.stream(directory.list()).filter(f -> f.endsWith(".man")).map(f -> f.replaceAll(".man", "" )).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Это решение не подходит, надо что бы с список попали файлы с расширением ".man", но без расширения, так как в папке могут быть и другие файлы они попасть не должны.